# += not working correctly?

Tags: c

Running this code, for whatever reason, prints out the correct values for each letter, and adds the first value to score, however, when it adds the second value, something goes wrong and it adds a seemingly random number.

values() is a function which assigns a set value to each integer in the array lValues which is used to determine the total value of wordCur which is a string.

```
int calcScore(char wordCur) {
    int score = 0;
    int conv;
    int wordLen = strlen(wordCur);
    int i;
    int *lValues[26];
    values(lValues);

    for (i = 0; i < wordLen; i++){
        conv = (int)wordCur[i] - 65;
        score += lValues[conv];
        printf("%d\n", lValues[conv]);
    }
    printf("\n%d\n", score);



return score;
}
```

Comment: Is it by intention that `wordCur` is not a character array pointer but a single character?

Comment: Can you give example data and run through your expected results

Comment: I suppose the parameter should be char* wordCur?

Comment: Are you sure that `wordCur` will never contain any lowercase letters? It looks like this code can only handle uppercase letters.

Comment: Also, lValues is an array of pointers - probably not what you want?

Answer (score 6):

your problem is:

```
int *lValues[26];
```

declares an array of pointers.

```
score += lValues[conv];
```

Adds the pointer rather than what's at the address (pointee)